# Linear Algebra - How to mentally visualize in 3d space a specific combo of vectors (Gilbert Strang's book - Introduction to Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, visualization

1.1 - Vectors & Linear Combinations (Introduction to Linear Algebra (5e) - Gilbert Strang)

(Pg 16)
Suppose the vectors u, v, w are in three-dimensional space:

1. What is the picture of all combinations cu?
2. What is the picture of all combinations cu + dv?
3. What is the picture of all combinations cu+ dv + ew?

If they are typical nonzero vectors (components chosen at random), here are the three answers :

1. The combinations cu fill a line through (0, 0, 0).
2. The combinations cu+ dv fill a plane through (0, 0, 0).
3. The combinations cu+ dv + ew fill three-dimensional space.

This is the typical situation! Line, then plane, then space. But other possibilities exist.
*When w happens to be cu + dv, that third vector w is in the plane of the first two.
The combinations of u, v, w will not go outside that uv plane. We do not get the full
three-dimensional space.*

**Query** - I'm not getting how to mentally visualize this specific case when w = cu + dv and " The combinations of u, v, w will not go outside that uv plane. "

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  When $u=(1,0,0)$, $v=(0,1,0)$, and $w=(1,1,0)$, any combination of $u, v, $ and $w$ has $z$-component $0$ and is in the $xy$-plane

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked

> how to mentally visualize this specific case when w = cu + dv and "The combinations of u, v, w will not go outside that uv plane."

Consider, e.g., $u=(1,0,0), v=(0,1,0), $ and $w=1u+1v=(1,1,0)$.

Any combination of $u, v, $ and $w$ has $z$-component $0$ and is in the $xy$-plane (which is the $uv$-plane).